# Error on import Select from 'material-ui/Select';

Tags: material-ui

I am working on my project using Meteor and just started using material-ui beta version, which looks very cool and buttons are displayed with no problems at all.

"material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.30" is the version I am using.

However, as soon as I add `import Select from 'material-ui/Select';`, 
I get following error. Strange...

Any help will be appreacted. Thanks,

```
modules.js?hash=f1b8010e8d8e8514a27b2c8d6dcdb4faaaaf587f:11047 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
es5-shim.js?hash=c070fc7aa1536cb75430d62c9dad8eaffe2b3716:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at es5-shim.js?hash=c070fc7aa1536cb75430d62c9dad8eaffe2b3716:17
    at es5-shim.js?hash=c070fc7aa1536cb75430d62c9dad8eaffe2b3716:2792
(anonymous) @ es5-shim.js?hash=c070fc7aa1536cb75430d62c9dad8eaffe2b3716:17
(anonymous) @ es5-shim.js?hash=c070fc7aa1536cb75430d62c9dad8eaffe2b3716:2792
promise.js?hash=ad77cb6d1ba5237250773fdb8936f8900a09be21:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at promise.js?hash=ad77cb6d1ba5237250773fdb8936f8900a09be21:17
    at promise.js?hash=ad77cb6d1ba5237250773fdb8936f8900a09be21:586
(anonymous) @ promise.js?hash=ad77cb6d1ba5237250773fdb8936f8900a09be21:17
(anonymous) @ promise.js?hash=ad77cb6d1ba5237250773fdb8936f8900a09be21:586
babel-runtime.js?hash=92770f08ed6cf73de1a4c0e25610b170df975dff:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at babel-runtime.js?hash=92770f08ed6cf73de1a4c0e25610b170df975dff:17
    at babel-runtime.js?hash=92770f08ed6cf73de1a4c0e25610b170df975dff:176
(anonymous) @ babel-runtime.js?hash=92770f08ed6cf73de1a4c0e25610b170df975dff:17
(anonymous) @ babel-runtime.js?hash=92770f08ed6cf73de1a4c0e25610b170df975dff:176
ecmascript-runtime-client.js?hash=236033036aa3b0629009d2af14113e2413052567:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at ecmascript-runtime-client.js?hash=236033036aa3b0629009d2af14113e2413052567:17
    at ecmascript-runtime-client.js?hash=236033036aa3b0629009d2af14113e2413052567:110
(anonymous) @ ecmascript-runtime-client.js?hash=236033036aa3b0629009d2af14113e2413052567:17
(anonymous) @ ecmascript-runtime-client.js?hash=236033036aa3b0629009d2af14113e2413052567:110
ejson.js?hash=3af8c8d41c63ca01c1c9698a677bc5ae971ff3b2:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at ejson.js?hash=3af8c8d41c63ca01c1c9698a677bc5ae971ff3b2:18
    at ejson.js?hash=3af8c8d41c63ca01c1c9698a677bc5ae971ff3b2:861
(anonymous) @ ejson.js?hash=3af8c8d41c63ca01c1c9698a677bc5ae971ff3b2:18
(anonymous) @ ejson.js?hash=3af8c8d41c63ca01c1c9698a677bc5ae971ff3b2:861
diff-sequence.js?hash=15014d7b1e11c05111a386992e684ab1d3cc4158:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EJSON' of undefined
    at diff-sequence.js?hash=15014d7b1e11c05111a386992e684ab1d3cc4158:18
    at diff-sequence.js?hash=15014d7b1e11c05111a386992e684ab1d3cc4158:297
(anonymous) @ diff-sequence.js?hash=15014d7b1e11c05111a386992e684ab1d3cc4158:18
(anonymous) @ diff-sequence.js?hash=15014d7b1e11c05111a386992e684ab1d3cc4158:297
geojson-utils.js?hash=e9d235fa7a29b6bcb50d7ad0b05751fa169fcc8b:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at geojson-utils.js?hash=e9d235fa7a29b6bcb50d7ad0b05751fa169fcc8b:17
    at geojson-utils.js?hash=e9d235fa7a29b6bcb50d7ad0b05751fa169fcc8b:442
(anonymous) @ geojson-utils.js?hash=e9d235fa7a29b6bcb50d7ad0b05751fa169fcc8b:17
(anonymous) @ geojson-utils.js?hash=e9d235fa7a29b6bcb50d7ad0b05751fa169fcc8b:442
id-map.js?hash=c7aea8dfa2bf46ff2ae0aa6c6cf09e36abc61d07:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EJSON' of undefined
    at id-map.js?hash=c7aea8dfa2bf46ff2ae0aa6c6cf09e36abc61d07:18
    at id-map.js?hash=c7aea8dfa2bf46ff2ae0aa6c6cf09e36abc61d07:123
(anonymous) @ id-map.js?hash=c7aea8dfa2bf46ff2ae0aa6c6cf09e36abc61d07:18
(anonymous) @ id-map.js?hash=c7aea8dfa2bf46ff2ae0aa6c6cf09e36abc61d07:123
random.js?hash=189ef930765405ef87a31a621407fc34447b8756:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at random.js?hash=189ef930765405ef87a31a621407fc34447b8756:18
    at random.js?hash=189ef930765405ef87a31a621407fc34447b8756:371
(anonymous) @ random.js?hash=189ef930765405ef87a31a621407fc34447b8756:18
(anonymous) @ random.js?hash=189ef930765405ef87a31a621407fc34447b8756:371
mongo-id.js?hash=345d169d517353f8146292b4abd24061721f8b26:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EJSON' of undefined
    at mongo-id.js?hash=345d169d517353f8146292b4abd24061721f8b26:17
    at mongo-id.js?hash=345d169d517353f8146292b4abd24061721f8b26:142
(anonymous) @ mongo-id.js?hash=345d169d517353f8146292b4abd24061721f8b26:17
(anonymous) @ mongo-id.js?hash=345d169d517353f8146292b4abd24061721f8b26:142
minimongo.js?hash=2b34314db9dbc6027d9d414887b75281c4515a19:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DiffSequence' of undefined
    at minimongo.js?hash=2b34314db9dbc6027d9d414887b75281c4515a19:17
    at minimongo.js?hash=2b34314db9dbc6027d9d414887b75281c4515a19:5160
(anonymous) @ minimongo.js?hash=2b34314db9dbc6027d9d414887b75281c4515a19:17
(anonymous) @ minimongo.js?hash=2b34314db9dbc6027d9d414887b75281c4515a19:5160
check.js?hash=eab389b8683d2f0b47a9d511894c2082fc6155a9:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at check.js?hash=eab389b8683d2f0b47a9d511894c2082fc6155a9:17
    at check.js?hash=eab389b8683d2f0b47a9d511894c2082fc6155a9:586
(anonymous) @ check.js?hash=eab389b8683d2f0b47a9d511894c2082fc6155a9:17
(anonymous) @ check.js?hash=eab389b8683d2f0b47a9d511894c2082fc6155a9:586
retry.js?hash=1e409617b538ff3e2b0238b15e45b3380c51a224:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Random' of undefined
    at retry.js?hash=1e409617b538ff3e2b0238b15e45b3380c51a224:18
    at retry.js?hash=1e409617b538ff3e2b0238b15e45b3380c51a224:110
(anonymous) @ retry.js?hash=1e409617b538ff3e2b0238b15e45b3380c51a224:18
(anonymous) @ retry.js?hash=1e409617b538ff3e2b0238b15e45b3380c51a224:110
ddp-common.js?hash=83c6dba3051ec76b5c1cd85d39357f0f501add98:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'check' of undefined
    at ddp-common.js?hash=83c6dba3051ec76b5c1cd85d39357f0f501add98:17
    at ddp-common.js?hash=83c6dba3051ec76b5c1cd85d39357f0f501add98:493
(anonymous) @ ddp-common.js?hash=83c6dba3051ec76b5c1cd85d39357f0f501add98:17
(anonymous) @ ddp-common.js?hash=83c6dba3051ec76b5c1cd85d39357f0f501add98:493
reload.js?hash=02487cd11db41d01f7837ad146e4680a9e8d2e12:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol' of undefined
    at reload.js?hash=02487cd11db41d01f7837ad146e4680a9e8d2e12:18
    at reload.js?hash=02487cd11db41d01f7837ad146e4680a9e8d2e12:309
(anonymous) @ reload.js?hash=02487cd11db41d01f7837ad146e4680a9e8d2e12:18
(anonymous) @ reload.js?hash=02487cd11db41d01f7837ad146e4680a9e8d2e12:309
ddp-client.js?hash=df770fd9a6a02fd730939b97d266ea2b12938e95:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'check' of undefined
    at ddp-client.js?hash=df770fd9a6a02fd730939b97d266ea2b12938e95:17
    at ddp-client.js?hash=df770fd9a6a02fd730939b97d266ea2b12938e95:5146
(anonymous) @ ddp-client.js?hash=df770fd9a6a02fd730939b97d266ea2b12938e95:17
(anonymous) @ ddp-client.js?hash=df770fd9a6a02fd730939b97d266ea2b12938e95:5146
ddp.js?hash=25dc3f428447c81620c91c4245dbc6e4f7d32fb7:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined
    at ddp.js?hash=25dc3f428447c81620c91c4245dbc6e4f7d32fb7:14
    at ddp.js?hash=25dc3f428447c81620c91c4245dbc6e4f7d32fb7:27
(anonymous) @ ddp.js?hash=25dc3f428447c81620c91c4245dbc6e4f7d32fb7:14
(anonymous) @ ddp.js?hash=25dc3f428447c81620c91c4245dbc6e4f7d32fb7:27
allow-deny.js?hash=74d8af62e9bac0bd3c45b254bad987e996a88f6e:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LocalCollection' of undefined
    at allow-deny.js?hash=74d8af62e9bac0bd3c45b254bad987e996a88f6e:17
    at allow-deny.js?hash=74d8af62e9bac0bd3c45b254bad987e996a88f6e:565
(anonymous) @ allow-deny.js?hash=74d8af62e9bac0bd3c45b254bad987e996a88f6e:17
(anonymous) @ allow-deny.js?hash=74d8af62e9bac0bd3c45b254bad987e996a88f6e:565
mongo.js?hash=337de4ed4979262aa9b84177742e90e72b1e1e1c:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AllowDeny' of undefined
    at mongo.js?hash=337de4ed4979262aa9b84177742e90e72b1e1e1c:17
    at mongo.js?hash=337de4ed4979262aa9b84177742e90e72b1e1e1c:832
(anonymous) @ mongo.js?hash=337de4ed4979262aa9b84177742e90e72b1e1e1c:17
(anonymous) @ mongo.js?hash=337de4ed4979262aa9b84177742e90e72b1e1e1c:832
webapp.js?hash=266b2d6adf1a164ef9db120ea9c68d5658351399:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at webapp.js?hash=266b2d6adf1a164ef9db120ea9c68d5658351399:18
    at webapp.js?hash=266b2d6adf1a164ef9db120ea9c68d5658351399:78
(anonymous) @ webapp.js?hash=266b2d6adf1a164ef9db120ea9c68d5658351399:18
(anonymous) @ webapp.js?hash=266b2d6adf1a164ef9db120ea9c68d5658351399:78
livedata.js?hash=7cf1831a60b48e304b054aee1ae0f7e38ff35d09:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined
    at livedata.js?hash=7cf1831a60b48e304b054aee1ae0f7e38ff35d09:14
    at livedata.js?hash=7cf1831a60b48e304b054aee1ae0f7e38ff35d09:31
(anonymous) @ livedata.js?hash=7cf1831a60b48e304b054aee1ae0f7e38ff35d09:14
(anonymous) @ livedata.js?hash=7cf1831a60b48e304b054aee1ae0f7e38ff35d09:31
dynamic-import.js?hash=d20b3dfd7dd31096c4c95f8751141e932cabc923:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meteorInstall' of undefined
    at dynamic-import.js?hash=d20b3dfd7dd31096c4c95f8751141e932cabc923:17
    at dynamic-import.js?hash=d20b3dfd7dd31096c4c95f8751141e932cabc923:444
(anonymous) @ dynamic-import.js?hash=d20b3dfd7dd31096c4c95f8751141e932cabc923:17
(anonymous) @ dynamic-import.js?hash=d20b3dfd7dd31096c4c95f8751141e932cabc923:444
autoupdate.js?hash=1fd9cf3472adaa6887170d88ab5ea1ddabf695fa:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Retry' of undefined
    at autoupdate.js?hash=1fd9cf3472adaa6887170d88ab5ea1ddabf695fa:19
    at autoupdate.js?hash=1fd9cf3472adaa6887170d88ab5ea1ddabf695fa:206
(anonymous) @ autoupdate.js?hash=1fd9cf3472adaa6887170d88ab5ea1ddabf695fa:19
(anonymous) @ autoupdate.js?hash=1fd9cf3472adaa6887170d88ab5ea1ddabf695fa:206
global-imports.js?hash=4260dcecfc88908c20291abbaeafd4320be072ac:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Mongo' of undefined
    at global-imports.js?hash=4260dcecfc88908c20291abbaeafd4320be072ac:3
(anonymous) @ global-imports.js?hash=4260dcecfc88908c20291abbaeafd4320be072ac:3
app.js?hash=eac09d9ff32c179f06c7dfe713dbe11902908405:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: meteorInstall is not defined
    at app.js?hash=eac09d9ff32c179f06c7dfe713dbe11902908405:1
```

Comment: Are you sure? Because the issue you posted is not related to material-UI. Looks like it’s meteor issue.